# How to iterate through data that are comming from database, when clicking a button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am making a website to submit answers for a questionnaire.

Every question is created by an admin from the dashboard, and the goal is to make the page dynamic by fetching the questions and answers for those questions from database.
Basically this:

[image: Picture of the form]

[image: Picture of the databse]

So the goal is when I click the answer of one of this buttons, to show up the next question (fetching the second question from the database also the three answers relating to that question and so on).

For the back-end developing I'm using pure PHP since I'm new to programming, and `PDO` for manipulating with data from database.

For managing with the data I am using Controllers, and for connecting with database I have made the connection on `/core/Database.php`

Any help is appreciated.. thanks for your time

Here is what i tried so far.

```
<?php
session_start();
require './controllers/UserController.php';

$user = new UserController;
$arr = $users=$user->getQuestions();
$index  = 0;

$answ1 = $user->getAnswers();
$index = 0;

$_SESSION['answerOne'] = $_POST['question1'];
// $_SESSION['answerTwo'] = $_POST['question2'];
// $_SESSION['answerThree'] = $_POST['question3'];
// $_SESSION['answerFour'] = $_POST['question4'];
echo $_SESSION['answerOne'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styling/questionstyle.css">
    <title>Question</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="hero">
        <div class="questionContainer">
            <div class="header">
                <img src="./assets/back.png" height="35%" class="backImage">
                <h2 class="questionNumber">01/04</h2>
            </div>
            <progress max="100" value="10"></progress>
            <h1 class="question">
            <?php echo $arr[$index]['description'] ?>

   </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="answerContainer">
            <img src="./assets/shadow.png" width="100%">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <button class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('q1').value ='a'"><h4 class="choice">a</h4><h4 class="answer"><?php echo $answ1[$index]['choice1']?></h4></button> <br>
                <button class="button2" onclick="document.getElementById('q1').value ='b'"><h4 class="choice">b</h4><h4 class="answer"><?php echo $answ1[$index]['choice2']?></h4></button> <br>
                <button class="button2"onclick="document.getElementById('q1').value ='c'" ><h4 class="choice">c</h4><h4 class="answer"><?php echo $answ1[$index]['choice3']?></h4></button>
                <input type="hidden" id="q1" name="question1">
                <input type="hidden" id="q2" name="question2"> 
                <input type="hidden" id="q3" name="question3"> 
                <input type="hidden" id="q4" name="question4"> 
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



</html>
```

```
<?php

include './core/Database.php';
?>
class UserController
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $query = $this->db->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function store($request)
    {
        isset($request['is_admin']) ? $isAdmin = 1 : $isAdmin = 0;
        $password = password_hash($request['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, is_admin) VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :is_admin)');
        $query->bindParam(':name', $request['fullName']);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $request['email']);
        $query->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $query->bindParam(':is_admin', $isAdmin);
        $query->execute();

        return header('Location: ./index.php');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
        $query->execute(['id' => $id]);

        return $query->fetch();
    }

    public function update($id, $request)
    {
        isset($request['is_admin']) ? $isAdmin = 1 : $isAdmin = 0;

        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = :name, email = :email, is_admin = :is_admin WHERE id = :id');
        $query->execute([
            'name' => $request['fullName'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'is_admin' => $isAdmin,
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        return header('Location: ./index.php');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id');
        $query->execute(['id' => $id]);
        return header('Location: ./index.php');
    }

    public function totalpa(){
        $query= $this->db->pdo->query('SELECT count(*) FROM user');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function totalfemra(){
        $query= $this->db->pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE gender='F'");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function totalmeshkuj(){
        $query=$this->db->pdo->query("SELECT count(*) from user WHERE gender ='M'");
        $query->execute(); 
        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }

    public function storeUser($req){ 
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user (city, gender, age) VALUES (:city, :gender, :age)');
        $query->bindParam(':city', $_SESSION['cityID']);
        $query->bindParam(':gender', $_SESSION['gender']);
        $query->bindParam(':age', $_SESSION['age']);
        $query->execute(); 
    }

    public function storeQuestion($req){
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO question(description) VALUES(:description)');
        $query->bindParam(':description',$_POST['pyetja']);
        $query->execute();

    }

    public function storeAnswer($param){
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare('INSERT into add_answer (q_id,choice1,choice2,choice3) VALUES(:q_id,:ch1,:ch2,:ch3)');
        $query->bindParam(':q_id',$param);
        $query->bindParam(':ch1', $_POST['choice1']);
        $query->bindParam(':ch2',$_POST['choice2']);
        $query->bindParam(':ch3',$_POST['choice3']);
        $query->execute();
    }

    public function getLastInsertedId(){
        $query=$this->db->pdo->prepare('SELECT MAX(qid) from question');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchColumn();
    }



    public function  getQuestions(){
        $query= $this->db->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM question');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getAnswers(){
        try{
        $query =$this->db->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM add_answer a INNER JOIN question q ON a.q_id = q.qid');
        $query -> execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            echo 'error';
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: So where is the code where you have attempted to get anything from the database

Comment: Edited to remove javascript tag because exept for an empty `<script>` tag there is no Javascript in the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly is on UserController as I explained above.. I can show you the code..

Comment: Well show us that or at least show us what it is producing by adding a `var_dump($arr);` and `var_dump($answ1);` and putting the output into your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I try to assign the values to the buttons from database it works like charm , everything works fine , but that is in static form, I need to iterate through them and if its question 1/4 , to show me the first question ,after I have answered the question 1 , to pass me to the second question 2/4 (onclick), Basically to iterate through that array of questions and answers, and if it's the first show it , if it's second show the second quesiton from db , but not in static way..P.s I updated the code for UserController, and thank you for your time bro.